# How will glusterFS performance degrade (if at all) with > 2 nodes

Tags: linux, aws, glusterfs

I have two API service nodes one Amazon Web Services. These nodes are mostly for servicing API calls. They also serve some image content.

There's a load balancer in the front so that URL http://service.myapp.com routes to either api1.myapp.com or api2.myapp.com.

To keep the content synchronized, I plan to use glusterFS. Optionally in future I can put a CDN on top of that.

The question is, if I need more service nodes in future, will the clusterFS performance degrade? If so it might be better to put all the content on another AWS node with a backup for redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I am an GlusterFs  beginner and I am not sure if I am correct. But according to http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/Performance_in_a_Gluster_Systemv6F.pdf.

The glusterFS cluster can achieve speeds of up-to 2 GB/s per storage node(theoretically?), so the performance will not degrade if the total throughout of your service nodes does not surpass 2 GB/s.